# Is there someting like Dispatcher.CheckAccess() when using Scheduler

Tags: system.reactive, scheduler, dispatcher

I want to do the equivalent of:

```
if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    // invoke synchronously if we are on the dispatcher thread
    collectionChangedEventHandler(this, args); 
}
else
{
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => collectionChangedEventHandler(this, args)));
}
```

I have not found a way to do this using an `IScheduler`.

Pseudo code for what I want:

```
if (scheduler.CheckAccess())
{
    collectionChangeEventHandler(sender, args);
}
else
{
    scheduler.Schedule(() => collectionChangeEventHandler(sender, args));
}
```

There is `CurrentThreadScheduler.ScheduleRequired` that looks promising but the documentation is sparse.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Scheduler is an abstraction over dispatching, so this kind of detail should always be hidden by the implementation.

Comment: @paulpdaniels I'm not sure I can explain in a short comment but I'm writing a thing that wraps an ObservableCollection<T> and relays colchanges to the Dispatcher thread if the scheduler passed in is the DispatcherScheduler.
Problem is that if I bind it to a datagrid and the datagrid adds a row the notification must be synchronous or wpf will  throw exceptions.
I have a workaround for it but am still curious.

Comment: Why are you using an Rx scheduler for this?

Comment: I have no ref to any wpf framework in the code. If it is used from wpf a DispatcherScheduler is passed in. Scheduler has been a good fit and also enabled testing things that would have been hard otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can write your own `CheckAccessDispatcherScheduler` that decorates `DispatcherScheduler`.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading/Reactive/Concurrency/DispatcherScheduler.cs

```
class CheckAccessDispatcherScheduler : LocalScheduler, ISchedulerPeriodic
{
    ...

    public override IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
    {
        if (decoratedDispatcher.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            action(this, state, Disposable.Empty);
            return Disposable.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return decoratedDispatcher.Schedule(state, action);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a solution, I don't love it as it requires users to use this scheduler and not the built in DispatcherScheduler. Feels like it will be error prone. +1 of course, I'm gonna leave the question open for a while.

Comment: Understandable, though it may be worth mentioning that the native Rx DispatcherScheduler is clearly intended to schedule work *asynchronously* on the Dispatcher. It's really an edge-case that async dispatch doesn't work for you. I wouldn't exactly be surprised to find out that there's a better solution for you that avoids this problem altogether and enables use of the native DispatcherScheduler as normal.

Comment: Yeah I have a solution where I don't use the scheduler at all. Asked this question because I was curious and it felt like there should be an elegant solution. Thank you again for your effort.